# Android 4.0.3 SDK Manager

Tags: android, sdk, windows-vista, eclipse-adt

How do you get the SDK Manager to "Run As Administrator" from inside Eclipse to get the packages properly installed?

Comment: you shouldn't have to, but if your still having problems you can manually start the sdk manager from the sdk directory

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could do that you can't update the tool or any libraries you are currently using so I would always update the SDK and tools outside of Eclipse as Administrator or similar privilege user.